# Haskell Asychronous exceptions

Tags: exception, haskell, asynchronous, parallel-processing, handler

I am using `forkIO` to spawn worker-threads. When a certain event happens I wish to 'reset' the workers. This should be able to happen an arbitrary number of times. I have my own type of exceptions, which we can call `data MyException = MyException`. We can imagine that the work is denoted by a `IO a` value.

My naive idea of doing this, before I read the documentation, was to define something like

```hs
    spawnWorkers :: Int -> MVar St -> IO ()
    spawnWorkers num jobs =
      sequence_ $ replicate num $ forkIO $ defHandler $ worker jobs
      where
        defHandler :: IO a -> IO a
        defHandler ioa = ioa `catch` \MyException -> defHandler ioa
```

However, this does not work. Inside the exception handler asynchronous exceptions are masked. The tail-call to `defHandler` does not have an associated exception handler.

What is the best way to achieve my desired functionality? I wish to rely only on `Control.Concurrent`, `Control.Concurrent.MVar`, and `Control.Exception`.

Comment: Don't use `forkIO`, or you will leak threads. Use `async` instead.  With respect to this use case of worker threads, look at the package called `scheduler`: https://github.com/lehins/scheduler

Comment: I am limited to using only `Control.Concurrent` and `Control.Exception`. @lehins

Comment: That would mean that this is just an exercise and your code will not in a production environment. In which case you are probably allowed bugs like leaking threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a value from the exception-handled action that tells whether the exception got thrown or not, then dispatch outside the exception handler. This pattern is wrapped up for you in the `try` function.

```
defHandler :: IO a -> IO a
defHandler ioa = try ioa >>= \case
    Left MyException -> defHandler ioa
    Right a -> pure a
```

But `try` isn't magic; it's just implemented in terms of `catch`.

```
try act = catch (Right <$> act) (pure . Left)
```

If you want, you can deforest, but I doubt it's worth the cost to the reader's sanity. At the very least leave yourself a note.

```
defHandler :: IO a -> IO a
defHandler ioa = join (catch (pure <$> ioa) (\MyException -> pure (defHandler ioa)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I saw this in the documentation but abstained because it was stated that `try` should not be used to capture asynchronous exceptions. There is not more elaboration, sadly.

Comment: @Rewbert Thanks for the tip. I just went and checked the documentation to see what you were talking about. There's actually quite a bit of elaboration -- the entire previous two paragraphs are about why. How frequently do you expect the asynchronous exception to be triggered? It looks pretty unlikely to me that you'll trigger the race condition discussed there -- you'd have to receive an exception between the end of `try ioa` and the beginning of the next call to `defHandler ioa` -- that is, in the short period where the `case` expression is being dispatched. (1/2)

Comment: If you are indeed worried about receiving asynchronous exceptions that frequently, then perhaps what you could do is restore/unmask inside the exception handler; however, to me it looks like this will cause a gradually growing stack, which may not be desirable. I don't see an obvious way to avoid that, though. (2/2)

Comment: @DanielWagner You can mask outside of the recursion, and close over the unmask action.

Comment: @Carl Ah, nice! I'll try to remember to write that up a bit later.

Comment: @DanielWagner It is much clearer now, thanks :)